# How to union multiple tables and perform paging in DB with Nhibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, union, paging

Is there any way to implement union and paging in DB?

eg:

```
(select A.col1 As ColumnA, A.col2 as ColumnB, A.col3 as ColumnC from table1 as A)
union
(select B.col1 as ColumnA, B.col2 as ColumnB, B.col3 as ColumnC from table2 as B)
```

I've found several solutions to implement this function, but paging is performed in memory, not in DB.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Use SQL query

This has several drawbacks, the most glaring one is that LIMIT and OFFSET are not standardized
across databases (Oracle even requires subquery) - so if you change db, the query will also need to be changed.

```
// PetDso is not NHibernate mapped, no virtual..
public class PetDto
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Owner { get; set; }
  public long Age { get; set; }
}

IList<PetDto> pets = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
      select NAME as Name, OWNER as Owner, AGE as Age from CAT 
      union 
      select DOG_NAME as Name, OWNER_NAME as Owner, AGE_IN_YEARS as Age from DOG 
      order by Name, Owner, Age LIMIT :returnedRows OFFSET :skipRows")
    .SetParameter("skipRows", 1)
    .SetParameter("returnedRows", 2)
    .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(PetDto)))
    .List<PetDto>();
```

### 2. Use view and map it

Create a view in db and map it (probably with <class mutable="false">). Be careful though, you will need an id for each row that won't change between queries, because NH is caching entities using id.

---

HQL doesn't support unions ([NH-2710](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2710)) and it should be the most complete way to query db.